# Reading from xml file using PHP to putput in html - error

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to read an XML file (not generated by me)
and output it in HTML

Code as below:

```html
<?php    $feed = "includes/captaincooks.xml";
$results = simplexml_load_file($feed); foreach ($results as $product);

//var_dump($results);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>    <ul>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $product->img_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->name; ?>" /></li>
        <li>Product URL: <?php echo $product->purl; ?> </li>
        <li>Description: <?php echo $product->desc; ?></li>
        <li>Price: <?php echo $product ->price; ?>  </li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $product->deeplink; ?>"<?php echo $product->product_name; ?>"></a></li>
    </ul>                                                     
 </body>
</html>
```

on the web page i get this error about an ';' ?

it seems to read the xml file and get the various bits of data just doesn't like something in the simplexml_load_file line 2

error is (showing 1 line only, many lines all pretty much the same except the data that's read)

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): includes/captaincooks.xml:1: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';' in /home/picnicpa/public_html/includes/captaincooks.html on line 2
```

`captaincooks.html` is the data i wrote above
`captaincooks.xml` is the xml file

Any ideas welcome

Tony

Answer (score 0):

The SimpleXML object will complain if the xml is not valid, so check the XML file and make sure is a well formed document, you could use use this online validator

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Answer (score 0):

`foreach ($results as $product);`
you've killed the loop with ; statement

for the loop try 
`foreach($array as $member){ do while looping }`

for easy xml handling i'd recommend for ["Xpath"](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp)

edit: Didn't notice I wasn't really answering your question
it seems your xml file is invalid
you can try opening it with a browser and see the error
or you can upload it here and we will try to help

Comment: I have tried a couple of validators, but they all return nothing, no error, no - it's ok !

Comment: regards you reply, if i have killed the loop why do i get repeat errors of the same but showing different data, as i t suggests it is continuing the loop anyway?